# Angular 8: Nested Service Dependencies results in Undefined

Tags: angular, service, async-await, rxjs, singleton

I have a Singleton Service (A) which depends on another Singleton Service (B).

In the constructor of A, when I attempt to get a property of B, I get a `TypeError: this.B is undefined.`

In the constructor of B, I make a backend call via another service.
It seems the backend call is causing something to break or halt and makes B unrecognizable by other service files.

#### Code Example:

```ts
// A Singleton Service. Relies on B.
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Aservice {
  constructor(private service: Bservice) {
    console.log('B isLoggedIn', this.service.isLoggedIn); // <-- triggers TypeError
  }
}
```

```ts
// B Singleton Service
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Bservice {
  isLoggedIn: boolean = false;

  constructor(private service: Cservice) {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    this.service.getSomeObject().subscribe(
      result => {
        console.log('B got result', result);
      },
      err => {
        console.error('B got ERROR', err);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

```ts
// C Singleton Service
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Cservice {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getSomeObject() {
    return this.http.get('my/api/path');
  }
}
```

Of course, I'm using this in a bit more complex way, but I've found that even just trying to access a defined variable inside B from A causes the TypeError.

This is unexpected and I haven't been able to figure out why `this.B is undefined`.

Comment: your code seems fine. could you try to reproduce it on stackblitz?

Comment: Is `this.Cservice.getSomeObject()` a typo? it should be `this.service.getSomeObject()`.  Also, not sure if this will help, but i've seen weird behavior due to hot reloading while editing a file.  Sometimes closing and restarting the server will resolve some weird issues.

Comment: This code seems to be working fine. I am able to get the isLoggedIn flag in Aservice. Please share code and try to reproduce the Error. The only thing you need to change is this.service.getSomeObject() line in BService.